# how to use variables as regular expression value?

Tags: regex, lisp, scheme, racket

For example:

```
(regexp-match #rx"a|b" "cat")
```

I would like to bind a variable to `"a|b"` so that I can create the pattern dynamically.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can build the pattern dynamically according to your needs (see the [documentation](http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/regexp-intro.html)), like this:

```
(regexp "a|b")
> #rx"a|b"
```

Notice that a *pattern* is just a string, the `regexp` procedure takes care of turning it into a regular expression object. The `#rx""` notation is just a literal representation of a regex, you can achieve the same effect by using the `regexp` procedure. After that, the regular expression can be bound to a variable:

```
(let ((regexp (regexp "a|b")))
  (regexp-match regexp "cat"))
```

Or used as a procedure parameter:

```
(define (matcher regexp)
  (regexp-match regexp "cat"))

(matcher (regexp "a|b"))
```

Or any other way you fancy.